# <script> attribute in the <head> tag without async or defer

Tags: javascript, html, browser

[image]Why Reddit has a  attribute in the  tag without async or defer? What are some of the cases that we have no choice but to block the parser?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to load scripts synchronously in case when the next script requires the helper functions from preloaded libraries. It is a hierarchy based loaded - "load the independent libraries on the top and then the dependent ones."

For example to use bootstrap.js functions, use must have jquery loaded before it and your script must be loaded after bootstrap.js to call its helper functions.

Comment: Let me make sure I've got this right: "async" does not run scripts in the order they were encountered so if a script (e.g. bootstrap.js) is depended upon another script (e.g. jquery.js)  it may not execute. So in case of jquery.js and bootstrap.js we can add the scripts in the <head> by adding the "defer" attribute or just before the closing <body> tag. Am I right?

Comment: @PictureElement the scripts loaded with scr attribute alone are loaded and executed immediately before further html parsing.

 async - stands for asynchronous loading,  so the scripts with async attribute will be loaded asynchronously by the browser.

and in case of defer keyword- scripts are loaded and executed after html parsing has been done.
so, yeah you can add scripts in head tag with defer or just before body ending without defer keyword, the result will be the same.